# Why can't I make multiple LookupRows in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud, ampscript

I feel like I'm in the fourth dimension again.

I want to accomplish 3 loops, and in each, first retrieve the total number of records from a DataExtension, then insert a new one.

Here is the code I came up with.

```
%%[

SET @LastName = "Jon"
SET @FirstName = "Snow"
SET @EmailAddress = "jon.snow@crowmail.com"
SET @DE = "MyDataExtension"    

FOR @i = 1 to 3 DO

    SET @DERows = LookupRows(@DE,'EmailAddress',@EmailAddress)

    OutputLine(concat("DERows: ",ROWCOUNT(@DERows),"<br>"))

    SET @Insert = InsertData(@DE,'Id',GUID(),'EmailAddress',@EmailAddress,'FirstName',@FirstName,'LastName',@LastName)

    OutputLine(concat("Inserted: ",@Insert,"<br>"))

NEXT @i

]%%
```

It should return

```
DERows: 0
Inserted: 1
DERows: 1
Inserted: 1
DERows: 2
Inserted: 1
```

But instead it returns

```
DERows: 0
Inserted: 1
DERows: 0
Inserted: 1
DERows: 0
Inserted: 1
```

As if the **LookupRows** function stops working after the first time it's executed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [ampscript](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) tags.

Comment: What's the context?  Email or CloudPage?

Comment: the context is a CloudPage